# Is there a way to programmatically activate Windows on Windows 7

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am working on a project where I need to activate Windows on a Windows 7 PC.  I wrote the code below using the Windows Software Licensing API.  MSDN says that the three functions used below require Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 which suggests that these functions aren't available on Windows 7.  But if I open slc.dll in depends.exe which is in C:\Windows\System32 on my Windows 7 machine, I do SLOpen and SLClose functions.  But not SLActivateProduct.

When I build the program I get linker error:

```
1>  main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SLActivateProduct@28 referenced in function _main
1>activate_windows.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

How does this work at link time?  I presume this means that slc.lib (see code  below) does not have the SLActivateProduct function?

This program doesn't need to be written in C so I can call anything from a script.  Anyone know if there would be any way of doing this on Windows 7?  It has to be a programmatic way which can be started by running a script.

code below:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Slpublic.h>
#include <slerror.h>

#include <stdio.h>

// lib to use
#pragma comment(lib, "slc.lib")

int main() {

  // slmgr.vbs has:
  // private const WindowsAppId = "55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f"
    // Windows AppId for SLID:  {55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f} - this is a GUID
    const SLID SLID_WINDOWS = {0x55c92734, 0xd682, 0x4d71, 0x98, 0x3e, 0xd6, 0xec, 0x3f, 0x16, 0x05, 0x9f};

    HSLC hslc;
    HRESULT hr = SLOpen(&hslc);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // try to activate windows
        hr = SLActivateProduct(hslc, &SLID_WINDOWS, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
        switch(hr) {
        case E_INVALIDARG:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - one or more arguments are not valid\n");
            break;
        case SL_E_PUBLISHING_LICENSE_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The license is not installed\n");
            break;
        case SL_E_PKEY_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The product key is not available\n");
            break;
        case SL_E_PRODUCT_SKU_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The license is not installed\n");
            break;

        case S_OK:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - returned S_OK\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - unknown return code\n");
            break;
        }
        hr=SLClose(hslc);
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation says what you're trying to use is available on Windows 8 and later. You know that this is the case, as per your OP. You still insist in trying to make use of those functions in Windows 7. You seem to act surprised that your code fails to link (clearly b/c the functions can't be found in the lib). Why do you insist and even post the question when you already know what you want to use is not available in Windows 7?

Comment: @ray Correct but I am asking for ANY way to do it.

Comment: Use a windows image which has been prepared for distribution with an already activated windows?

Comment: @RedX should that make any difference?  The process of system preparation is supposed to generalise the deployed image.

Comment: @ray: MSDN documentation is often misleading in regards to minimum supported OS versions for APIs. Case in point, MSDN says `SLOpen()` and `SLClose()` are available only on Win8+, but they are actually available on Win7 as well. But `SLActivateProduct()` is definitely not on Win7, I checked.  Linker errors have nothing to do with OS version, though, and everything to do with development environment.  The version of `slc.lib` in the OP's dev tools is missing a reference to `SLActivateProduct()` even when compiling for Win8 deployment.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I could try linking with win8 import library and adding win8 such. Delivery to deployment path. Not sure if that would be legal though

Comment: @RemyLebeau Maybe, but the fact that functions exist doesn't mean they work or that the entire feature set is present. It sounds like win7 content is incomplete, hence not supported.

Comment: It would probably be a lot simpler to call `slmgr.vbs` to do the work on your behalf.

Comment: @ray Win7 has a complete Software Licensing API beyond just `SLOpen()`/`SLClose()` (which would be pretty useless by themselves). It just doesn't have `SLActivateProduct()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SLActivateProduct()` is simply not available on Windows 7, even if you could link to it at compile-time (which apparently you cannot since your version of `slc.lib` is missing that reference).

However, you can load `SLActivateProduct()` dynamically at runtime using `GetProcAddress()`.  That will get you past the linker error (until you update your development environment) and allow your code to work on Windows 8 and later, at least.

And FYI, `sliddefs.h` defines a `WINDOWS_SLID` constant, so you do not need to define it manually in your code.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Slpublic.h>
#include <slerror.h>
#include <sliddefs.h>

#include <stdio.h>

// lib to use
#pragma comment(lib, "slc.lib")

// if your version of Slpublic.h does not define these then uncomment this...
/*
typedef enum _tagSL_ACTIVATION_TYPE { 
  SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE_DEFAULT           = 0,
  SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY  = 1
} SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE;

typedef struct _tagSL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER {
  DWORD              cbSize;
  SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE type;
} SL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER;
*/

typedef HRESULT WINAPI (*LPFN_SLActivateProduct)(HSLC, const SLID*, UINT, const PVOID, const SL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER*, PCWSTR, WORD);

int main()
{
    LPFN_SLActivateProduct lpSLActivateProduct = (LPFN_SLActivateProduct) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("slc.dll")), "SLActivateProduct");
    if (!lpSLActivateProduct)
    {
        printf("SLActivateProduct - The product cannot be activated on this system\n");
        return 0;
    }

    HSLC hslc;

    HRESULT hr = SLOpen(&hslc);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("SLOpen - unknown return code 0x%08X\n", hr);
        return 0;
    }

    // try to activate windows
    hr = lpSLActivateProduct(hslc, &WINDOWS_SLID, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
    switch(hr)
    {
        case E_INVALIDARG:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - one or more arguments are not valid\n");
            break;

        case SL_E_PUBLISHING_LICENSE_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The license is not installed\n");
            break;

        case SL_E_PKEY_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The product key is not available\n");
            break;

        case SL_E_PRODUCT_SKU_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The license is not installed\n");
            break;

        case S_OK:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - returned S_OK\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - unknown return code 0x%08X\n", hr);
            break;
    }

    hr = SLClose(hslc);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Update**: it turns out `SLActivateProduct()` **IS** available on Windows 7, after all.  It is simply located in `slcext.dll` instead of `slc.dll`, like MSDN says.  You can adjust the `GetProcAddress()` call accordingly:

```
LPFN_SLActivateProduct lpSLActivateProduct = (LPFN_SLActivateProduct) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("slc.dll")), "SLActivateProduct");
if (!lpSLActivateProduct)
{
    // TODO: if SLCEXT.DLL is not already loaded, use LoadLibrary() instead of GetModuleHandle()...
    lpSLActivateProduct = (LPFN_SLActivateProduct) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("slcext.dll")), "SLActivateProduct");
}
if (!lpSLActivateProduct)
{
    printf("SLActivateProduct - The product cannot be activated on this system\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Update**: if later on down the road, you update to a development environment whose `slc.lib` is no longer missing a reference to `SLActivateProduct()`, you can remove the explicit call to `GetProcAddress()` and instead use the linker's [delay loaded DLLs feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx).  That allows you to write code as-if you were static linking, but then the linker injects special code that will call `GetProcAddress()` for you the first time the DLL function is called at runtime.  That will allow you to check the OS version before calling the function "statically", allowing your app to still run on older Windows versions but only perform activation on Windows 7+.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Slpublic.h>
#include <slerror.h>
#include <sliddefs.h>

#include <stdio.h>

// lib to use
#pragma comment(lib, "slc.lib")

// if your version of Slpublic.h does not define these then uncomment this...
/*
typedef enum _tagSL_ACTIVATION_TYPE { 
  SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE_DEFAULT           = 0,
  SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY  = 1
} SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE;

typedef struct _tagSL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER {
  DWORD              cbSize;
  SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE type;
} SL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER;
*/

int main()
{
    OSVERSIONINFO osi = {0};
    osi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osi).
    GetVersionEx(&osi);

    if ((osi.dwMajorVersion < 6) || ((osi.dwMajorVersion == 6) && (dwMinorVersion < 1)))
    {
        printf("SLActivateProduct - The product cannot be activated on this system\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // alternatively:
    /*
    #include <VersionHelpers.h>

    if (!IsWindows7OrGreater())
    {
        printf("SLActivateProduct - The product cannot be activated on this system\n");
        return 0;
    }
    */

    HSLC hslc;

    HRESULT hr = SLOpen(&hslc);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("SLOpen - unknown return code 0x%08X\n", hr);
        return 0;
    }

    // try to activate windows
    hr = SLActivateProduct(hslc, &WINDOWS_SLID, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
    switch(hr)
    {
        case E_INVALIDARG:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - one or more arguments are not valid\n");
            break;

        case SL_E_PUBLISHING_LICENSE_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The license is not installed\n");
            break;

        case SL_E_PKEY_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The product key is not available\n");
            break;

        case SL_E_PRODUCT_SKU_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The license is not installed\n");
            break;

        case S_OK:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - returned S_OK\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - unknown return code 0x%08X\n", hr);
            break;
    }

    hr = SLClose(hslc);

    return 0;
}
```

However, to address the `slc.dll` vs `slcext.dll` issue, you can use a [delay-load failure hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfcfb0a3.aspx) to detect when `SLActivateProduct()` is not found in `slc.dll`, and then load it from `slcext.dll` instead.

In fact, this is the preferred option, as it also provides another opportunity - it allows you to remove the OS version check altogether!  If `SLActivateProduct()` is not found in either DLL, you can return a pointer to a custom user-defined function instead.  When the code calls `SLActivateProduct()`, and if it calls that function, it could simply return `E_NOTIMPL`, which `main()` can handle in its `switch` statement:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Slpublic.h>
#include <slerror.h>
#include <sliddefs.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <delayimp.h> 

// lib to use
#pragma comment(lib, "slc.lib")

// if your version of Slpublic.h does not define these then uncomment this...
/*
typedef enum _tagSL_ACTIVATION_TYPE { 
  SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE_DEFAULT           = 0,
  SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY  = 1
} SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE;

typedef struct _tagSL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER {
  DWORD              cbSize;
  SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE type;
} SL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER;
*/

HRESULT WINAPI Dummy_SLActivateProduct(HSLC, const SLID*, UINT, const PVOID, const SL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER*, PCWSTR, WORD)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

HMODULE hSlcExtDll = NULL;

FARPROC WINAPI MyDliFailureHook(unsigned dliNotify, PDelayLoadInfo  pdli)
{
    if ((dliNotify == dliFailGetProc) && (pdli->dlp.fImportByName) && (lstrcmpA(pdli->dlp.szProcName, "SLActivateProduct") == 0))
    {
        hSlcExtDll = LoadLibrary("slcext.dll");
        FARPROC fn = GetProcAddress(hSlcExtDll, "SLActivateProduct");
        if (!fn) fn = &Dummy_SLActivateProduct;
        return fn;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    __pfnDliFailureHook2 = &MyDliFailureHook; 

    HSLC hslc;

    HRESULT hr = SLOpen(&hslc);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("SLOpen - unknown return code 0x%08X\n", hr);
        return 0;
    }

    // try to activate windows
    hr = SLActivateProduct(hslc, &WINDOWS_SLID, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
    switch(hr)
    {
        case E_NOTIMPL:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The product cannot be activated on this system\n");
            break;

        case E_INVALIDARG:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - one or more arguments are not valid\n");
            break;

        case SL_E_PUBLISHING_LICENSE_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The license is not installed\n");
            break;

        case SL_E_PKEY_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The product key is not available\n");
            break;

        case SL_E_PRODUCT_SKU_NOT_INSTALLED:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - The license is not installed\n");
            break;

        case S_OK:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - returned S_OK\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("SLActivateProduct - unknown return code 0x%08X\n", hr);
            break;
    }

    hr = SLClose(hslc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I will call slmgr -ato from a script to do the activation.  Testing that at the moment.  but your answer was certainly useful.

Comment: @AngusComber: The tooltip for the up-arrow to the left of this answer reads: *"This answer is useful"*.

Comment: @Remy lebeau what is `WINDOWS_SLID` and how to initialize it

Comment: @loaded_dypper as I stated in my answer above: "*And FYI, sliddefs.h defines a WINDOWS_SLID constant, so you do not need to define it manually in your code.*" It is defined in sliddefs.h as: `DEFINE_GUID(WINDOWS_SLID, 0x55c92734, 0xd682, 0x4d71, 0x98, 0x3e, 0xd6, 0xec, 0x3f, 0x16, 0x05, 0x9f);` So, it is a `GUID` with a value of `{55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f}`

Comment: @RemyLebeau cannot use `sliddefs.h` with mingw64 compiler errors  `fatal error: sliddefs.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: @loaded_dypper that is because ming sucks for Windows development, it usually has outdated SDKs, missing/incomplete files, etc.